# Error running Astar parachains with zombienet

Tags: parachain, astar, zombienet

I'm following this [example](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/third-party/zombienet/multi_parachains.toml) but I always get an error:

[image]

My config.toml:

```
[settings]
timeout = 1000

[relaychain]
default_command = "./bin/polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "charlie"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "dave"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
chain = "shibuya-dev"
cumulus_based = true

  [[parachains.collators]]
  name = "collator1"  
  command = "./bin/astar-collator"
  args = [ "-l=xcm=trace", "--enable-evm-rpc" ]

[[parachains]]
id = 2007
chain = "shiden-dev"
cumulus_based = true

  [[parachains.collators]]
  name = "collator2"  
  command = "./bin/astar-collator"
  args = [ "-l=xcm=trace", "--enable-evm-rpc" ]

[[hrmp_channels]]
  sender = 2000
  recipient = 2007
  max_capacity = 8
  max_message_size = 512
  
[[hrmp_channels]]
  sender = 2007
  recipient = 2000
  max_capacity = 8
  max_message_size = 512
```

My folder structure:

[image]

run-astar.sh:

```
./zombienet -p native spawn config-astart.toml
```

I'm using macbook pro M1. Do I need something else to configure?

Comment: Check this part of the Substrate docs, to check if you have the right set up for zombienet: https://docs.substrate.io/test/set-up-a-test-network/#configure-the-test-network-settings

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I had to change de parachaind Id

Comment: Great, write your solution as an answer so can benefit other people that might experiment the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the first id to 2006 and It worked.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up answer :)